# Stop python sub-process leaving behind dead 'python' process

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am working on a python program which has to run a (possibly large) number of other python programs (for some load testing). Some of these are short-lived and others keep going for longer. I want the short-lived ones to terminate and disappear when they are done, but each one seems to leave behind a dead "(Python)" process until the original program finishes.

Platform is OSX, Python 2.7.6.

Here are simple demo programs that show the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Child Process: Started by parent...
import time
print "Hello from child!"
time.sleep(10)
print "Child finished."
exit(0)
```

And the parent program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Parent process:
import subprocess, time
print "Starting Child..."
child = subprocess.Popen( "./child.py" )
print "Parent Process... hanging around."
time.sleep(30)
exit(0)
```

I run the "parent" program from the terminal with "./parent.py". Here's the output (as expected):

```
Starting Child...
Parent Process... hanging around.
Hello from child!
Child finished.
```

Initially the 'ps' command shows this:

'ps' command shows this:

```
782 ttys002    0:00.03 python ./parent.py
783 ttys002    0:00.02 python ./child.py
```

This makes sense... the parent has launched the child process.

After 10 seconds, the child finishes as expected, and 'ps' then shows:

```
782 ttys002    0:00.03 python ./parent.py
783 ttys002    0:00.00 (Python)
```

'783' then hangs around until the parent process finishes, even though the python program has already done "exit(0)".

Is there any way to actually terminate / get rid of this process once it's done? I'm thinking it might be an issue if I launch hundreds or even thousands of short-lived processes over a long time.

I've experimented with subprocess(), Popen (as shown), and also using fork() and then execl(), but they always end up with the same behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call child.wait at some point.

Comment: I'd guess that this is the issue. It looks like a defunct process waiting to be repeated. Read the exit code and it'll disappear

Comment: That's it - thanks! I've done this in C, but for some reason I assumed Python would handle it. Just read the docs again and noticed the "Popen.wait()" method.

Comment: In fact I don't want my main process to wait for the child (I want "fire and forget"), and polling with child.poll() is a bit messy, so I created a new thread to launch the child. The thread can then wait in 'child.wait()' and the main thread can continue. This seems to work OK.

Comment: @Jeremy Every time you create a new Popen instance python polls already existing childs. See subprocess._cleanup.

Comment: You can keep a list of started children and call child.wait at end of your parent script. There is no need in threads.

Comment: @TasosVogiatzoglou: s/repeated/reaped/

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Indeed :)